# Прямая речовка таки (другими словами, прямая речь)

Tags: прямая-речь

Как правильно?

> Можно ли сказать: «Я рядом с метро» вместо «Я рядом с метростанцией»?

> Можно ли сказать «Я рядом с метро» вместо «Я рядом с метростанцией»?

Comment: «Я рядом я метро», - как понимать опечатку? Предлог ***в*** , ***с*** или ***у***?

Comment: Речовка -  «небольшой ритмически организованный текст патриотического содержания, исполненный группой пионеров хором в процессе строевой ходьбы».

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр  Приведите, пжста, текст речовки. Чтобы содержание было понятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны **оба варианта:**

(1) **Можно ли сказать:** «Я рядом с метро» вместо «Я рядом с метростанцией»?

Дословные высказывания оформляются по правилам для прямой речи, предлог ***вместо*** относится ко второму высказыванию.

(2) **Можно ли сказать** «я рядом с метро» вместо «я рядом с метростанцией»?

Дословное высказывание оформляется как член предложения. Лучше использовать **строчные** буквы.

Answer (score 1):

**ВСЁ О РЕЧОВКАХ:**

Как их правильно **составлять** и как правильно записывать слово "***речовка***".

Лучше так (если ритмическая речовка):

*Я рЯдом, // я **в** метрО.*

Или: *Я рЯдом, // **у** метрО.*

А то непонятно, где искать (у входа или на самой станции).

**Примечание**

В словаре: **речовка**.  Но орфографический редактор подчеркивает слово как неправильное.

**[Про речовку](https://vk.com/wall-184314764_821)**

Comment: Шаронушка, поправь шапку вопроса - не то снесут!

«Я рядом я метро», - как понимать опечатку? Предлог ***в***, ***с*** или ***у***? – 
   
Речовка - «небольшой ритмически организованный текст патриотического содержания, исполненный группой пионеров хором в процессе строевой ходьбы».

Comment: А может, сами исправите и ответик дадите, чтобы про речовку было. Я люблю ваши ответы)

Comment: Автор, видимо, про двоеточие спрашивал.

Comment: Артем, ну какое в речовке может быть двоеточие?)   Это же ритмическая речь, там запятой вполне достаточно.  Предлог бы выбрать)

Comment: Sharon, посмотрите, пожалуйста, на варианты Лео. Никакой речовки там нет, это его обычные "запятушонки". Речь идёт о двоеточии при прямой **речи** ("речовке").

Comment: Спасибо, я дала второй ответ.  Надо вопросы записывать понятно.  И сама речовка непонятно к чему упомянута.  Стилевые приемы в вопросе нежелательны. Отсюда все проблемы и разговоры.  Так что второй вариант я убирать не буду.

Comment: "Я люблю ваши ответы)" - ты на БВ сходи - я там рассказываю истории.

Comment: Я захожу, по возможности)  Там вы неподражаемы!  Вам бы книгу свою написать, вот что хорошо  бы.  Подумайте)  Но еще  я люблю, когда вы здесь отвечаете.  А то в наших ответах мало художественности и душевности)  Всё правила пересказываем да грамматику подбираем, ну примеры какие найдем.  А творчества мало даже в этом, почти что совсем нет.

Answer (score 1):

Речовка-кричалка - это "я за метро". Метростанция явно выбивается из ритма.

Когда находишься на опушке леса, можно конечно сказать "я у осины", но обычно говорят "я у леса"...

Comment: Ага, у леса!  Ищи ветра в поле. У осины конкретнее, только надо добавить описание осины.  А вообще я представила: Лео со товарищи устраивают перфоманс у метростанции.  Слышу "речовка" – и сразу картинку вижу, а не прямую речь.

Comment: @Sharon а еще у леса бывают разные названия входов. А осины все осины. Хотя, даже не у осины, а у дерева. Перформанс не котик устраивает, он просто пишет похожие, но не уместные словоформы, получаются непривычные сочетания слов, и это возбуждает у вас фантазии.

Comment: Тогда придумайте речовку с названием входа, то есть осины. И чтобы ритмическая  была.

Comment: @Sharon Зенит - чемпион!

Comment: Какой же это перфоманс! В чем здесь творческое начало? Это же форма современного искусства, жанр театрально-художественного представления.  Креативность нужна во всем.

Comment: @Sharon творчество и креативность - это не одно и тоже.

Comment: Это как раз одо и тоже: create – создавать, творить.

Comment: @Sharon это перевод слова. Креатив от растить, выращивать, а творить родственно говорить, варить. Креатив - это опосредованное действие на другого, другое, а творчество - это самовоздействие. Когда вы говорите про креативность, вы требуете некой динамики, чем кстати побуждаете меня что-то делать... Креатив неразрывно связан с манипулятивным воздействием на другого, переносом агрессии. Ну и это западных подход к созданию, то есть когда возникает потребность в чём-то, нужно найти и пнуть того, кто это может сделать, этим вы и занимаетесь) это и называется креативность.

Comment: Сказать "это у вас креативно получилось"  – значит пнуть кого-то? А кого? Всех остальных?  Да уж, у вас научишься хорошему))

Comment: @Sharon не совсем, сказать "у вас получилось креативно" - значит вернуть пинок.

Comment: А если так: Раньше у вас всё было бездарно, а теперь вроде как ничего. Я вас так понимаю. Коммуникативность – вот что важно.

Comment: @Sharon коммуникативность - это свойство или навык воспитанный у кого-то, выращенный, созданный, привитый. Я кстати нашёл откуда это слово тоже.

Comment: Тоже оттуда?...  Вместе с бытовой техникой?

Comment: У Аристотеля есть книжка - Политика. Вот оттуда про коммуникацию и общение, но коммуникативность и коммуникация - это слова разные, как нагретый и теплый.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!  Это уже другая тема.

Comment: Такъ, кромЪ собственчелнока, при помощи его дфлается еще

паго употребленйя авллють

нЪчто другое, а платье и кровать только сами соет предметъ употреблешя. Если производство и дЪйствас, будучи различны по виду, требуютъ дли себя иявфстныхь орудш, то и самых эти орудя необходимо должны имфть между собою тоже самое различ. Жизнь есть дЪйстве, а не производство. - не может нормально определить дореформенный шрифт)

Comment: Короче Аристотель говорит, что люди общаются и создают законы и государство, и с другой стороны государство нужно, чтобы человек был человеком, потому что без понимания законов - принципов общения, он либо зверь либо бог. Но есть люди которые общаются и создают общие понятия - хозяева, а есть те, кто ими руководствуется - рабы.  И хозяева руководят рабами не через понимание слов-понятий, а через значение слов. Раб же не может осознать слово, так как неразумен, но в тоже время он не животное, раб сознателен, поэтому знает значение слов и это побуждает его производить продукт. Как-то так.